# How to fake a filesystem that cannot be mounted by others

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, kernel, mount

I'm currently working on a project. There's an Ubuntu Linux system installed on a disk, DA, mounting the other disk, DB.

What it requires is that DB can be only mounted by DA in order to prevent data stealing. I planned to use encryption tools provided by Ubuntu to encrypt the whole disk DB. Other Linux won't be able to mount DB since they don't have the right key.

However, my colleague told me it is possible to modify the kernel to make a "fake" new filesystem, say, ext9, and this new filesystem is actually `ext3` or `ext4`. Since only the new kernel knows this "new" filesystem, other Linux would never get it mounted. And since it in fact is `ext3`, software like Apache or MySQL could run normally.

Is this possible or not.

Comment: Something tells me, though I haven't looked at sources and am not sure, that you could simply modify the `mount.ext4` (or other "filesystem-specific" `mount` command) command to not check for filesystem type when trying to mount, so that would defeat this.

Comment: I think encryption is by far the more secure alternative.

Comment: sounds feasible. However not secure, and if someone else has the same idea and you put the disk on there system then it will get mounted.

Comment: Your original idea is much better. Anyone who wants to steal your colleague's data only needs to look at the beginning of the unencrypted drive to see it is really ext3 and get it mounted. He is putting all his trust in a "black box" while your plan actually secures the data. If you do end up using his plan, combine them and encrypt anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in your title: how to fake a filesystem that cannot be mounted by others? Write random data. It's a fake filesystem and nobody will be able to mount it.

To answer the question you're asking: sure, you can fake a filesystem this way, but it's equally trivial to un-fake. Others *can* definitely mount it, it's just that they'll have to go and change a setting somewhere, it won't be automatic. This is as secure as putting a “turtleneck sweaters” label on your jewelry drawer: it only works as long as nobody bothers to look.

As for the answer to your problem, you already know it. If you don't want others to be able to mount the disk, you need to make what's stored on the disk unusable without some secret that only you know. This is called encryption. Use dm-crypt.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but it's security through obscurity. It's not securing anything.  It's like putting something in a box but not locking it up.